# Do rsync at the same time to the same destination

Tags: linux, rsync

I have 10 production servers, What will happen when :

1. I still doing rsync for file (A,B,C), meanwhile at the same time my friends also do rsync for file (D,E,F) to the same production machine ?
2. What if i and friends do rsync to the same file at the same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity 1 will work just fine. Activity 2 will fail in some unspecified way. If you want to do n-way merges, use a VCS.